# Keep contents of a container view in Navigation Stack

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `HomeViewcontroller` where I have a segmented controller that toggles between three `UICollectionViews` in a container.

HomeViewContainer is the root of my navigation controller

```
class HomeViewContainer: UIViewController {

    let displayOptionSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Businesses","List","Map"])
        segmentedControl.setupBasicControllerColors()
        return segmentedControl
    }()

    let businessCollectionViewController = BusinessCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let couponCollectionViewController = CouponCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    var currentSegmentIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainWhite()

        setupHeaderView()
        add(asChildViewController: businessCollectionViewController)

    }


    fileprivate func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        contentContainer.addChildViewController(viewController)
        contentContainer.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    fileprivate func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

        viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    @objc func segmentedValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        if currentSegmentIndex != sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            switch currentSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                remove(asChildViewController: businessCollectionViewController)
            case 1, 2:
                remove(asChildViewController: couponCollectionViewController)
            default:
                break
            }

            //Add new view based on user chosen option.
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                currentSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
                add(asChildViewController: businessCollectionViewController)
            case 1:
                currentSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
                couponCollectionViewController.toggleMapHeaderOff()
                add(asChildViewController: couponCollectionViewController)
            case 2:
                currentSegmentIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
                couponCollectionViewController.toggleMapheaderOn()
                add(asChildViewController: couponCollectionViewController)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The views display correctly but the problem becomes when I click on a cell in one of my collection views.

For example, if I click on a cell in my businessCollectionViewController, I try presenting another ViewController in my navigation controller and I cant.

```
BusinessCollectionViewController

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let bdvc = BusinessDetailViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        //NOTHING HAPPENS HERE
        self.navigationController?.present(bdvc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

How do I make it so that the content of **ContentContainer** still within the **HomeViewContainer** navigation stack? I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the **add()** method in my **HomeViewContainer** class, but I don't know what is an appropriate solution to take.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I needed to actually add the ContentContainer as a child to my HomeViewContainer.

In HomeViewContainer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainWhite()

    //Added this line!
    addChildVC(vc: contentContainer, toView: self.view)

    setupHeaderView()
    add(asChildViewController: businessCollectionViewController)

}

//And added this helper method
public func addChildVC(vc: UIViewController, toView containerView: UIView) {
    addChildViewController(vc)
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.width, height: containerView.frame.height)
    print("Container Frame = \(containerView.frame)")
    vc.view.frame = frame
    containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```